# Missing setup_module table in Magento 2.3.2 database

Tags: magento2, module, setup, table, custom-extension

i am missing a table setup_module in magent 2.3.2 database,

the site is working, however i cannot install any extensions as the new tables are not being created due to missing setup_module.

i could figure out the table columns as, not confirmed on data fields

> module - PRIMARY KEY TEXT NOT NULL,
>
> data_version - TEXT NOT NULL,
>
> schema_version - TEXT NOT NULL,

if someone can send a screen shot of setup_module it can help.

[found a post saying rename env.php and install magento 2.3.2 again](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Setup-Module-Table-is-missing-in-My-database-and-Unable-to/td-p/129455)

Comment: Just login to your database server and create the table?

Comment: @Black is there any where to find columns, datatype to create in setup_module table

Comment: Just download and setup a fresh magento and copy the table from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your database then run this:

```
CREATE TABLE `setup_module` (
 `module` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Module',
 `schema_version` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Schema Version',
 `data_version` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Data Version',
 PRIMARY KEY (`module`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Module versions registry'
```

Pulled directly from a fresh Magento 2.3 install. You might also do a clean Magento 2 install then compare schemas to see if you're missing anything else.